# Check internet connection with alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my app,i check internet connection and when user have no internet the he show a alert dialog.this alert dialog have to button."Close" button close this application and "Go to Setting" button goes to the user phone setting.I do perfectly this but when user on his internet connection and back to this app user show this alert dialog.but i don't show this alert dialog when he on his internet connection then he goes to the mainactivity in app.

```
    InternetCheck.isConnected(this);

    logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);
    rotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotate);
    logo.setAnimation(rotateAnimation);
    splash_progressBar = findViewById(R.id.splash_progressBar);
    splash_progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (InternetCheck.isConnected(getApplicationContext())){
                Intent next = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(next);
                finish();
            }else{
                showDialog();
                splash_progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    },SPLASH_OUT);
}

private void showDialog() {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_dialog,null);


    Button clsBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.closeBtn);
    Button setttingBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.settingBtn);

    clsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();

        }
    });

    setttingBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
        }
    });


    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(view)
            .create();

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

How can i do this.Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by  "i don't show this alert dialog when he on his internet connection then he goes to the mainactivity in app" ? Please clarify your question

Comment: suppose user have no internet connection,then he see alert dialog,and tap "Go to setting" button the he goes to his phone setting and on hinternet connection.then he back to this app and don't see alert dialog and goes to mainactivity i n this app

Comment: It's normal he does not see the dialog when he goes back to the app since internet connexion is on

Comment: @matdev yes,but how can i do this?can u explain me

Comment: Have you implemented onActivityResult() ? This is how you handle result from an other activity

Comment: @matdev no,i am not implemented onActivityResult()

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle result from an other activity, you should override `onActivityResult()` in your SplashActivity.

Also when you call startActivityForResult(), it's good practice to provide a non zero value as the requestCode arguement.

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_SETTINGS = 1;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_SETTINGS) {

        //Handle the result from settings activity
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (InternetCheck.isConnected(getApplicationContext())){
                    Intent next = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(next);
                    finish();
                } else{
                    showDialog();
                    splash_progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        },SPLASH_OUT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am using handler. can you share full code with handler, please?

Comment: Sorry sir it's doesn't work.can i share sample video clip of app of app?@matdev

Comment: The question is when user on his/her internet connection,this app restart automatically and goes to next activity.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Please clarify your question with A: The desired behaviour of your app B: The observed behaviour of your app